# when i install wagtailtrans it shows error

Tags: django, wagtail

```
Moving to c:
\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pil\
from C: 
\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~il
Moving to c:
\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pillow-8.3.2.dist-info\
from C:
\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~illow-8.3.2.dist-info
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' - u - c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r132d9vs\\pillow_2201a7b052fc4b8aa3f08901eaf540e4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r132d9vs\\pillow_2201a7b052fc4b8aa3f08901eaf540e4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from
            setuptools import setup
            setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install - -record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ll058sa9\install-record.txt' - -single-version-externally-managed - -compile - -install-headers 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\Pillow' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: "Check the logs for full command output" have you checked those logs?

Comment: which logs ,,,,,?